# How to log software actions

Tags: windows-7

How can I log every action a program takes on my computer? I'd like to log things like creating files, writing/reading the registry, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example of such software is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).